# Http2 not working with express

Tags: node.js, express, https, server, http2

I have `server.js` file where is some code

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var fs = require('fs');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, http2!')
})

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.crt')
};

require('http2').createServer(options, app).listen(8080);
```

After that I run in shell

```
$ node server.js
```

And server is waiting, but I can't open it. I tried http://localhost:8080 and https://localhost:8080 (I know that this is one is right one.). But nothing is going on, no errors no response in browser, what am I doing wrong? Also `.key` and `.crt` files not generated by me, I just copied it, can this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it wasn't http2 issue, just firefox doesn't want to open it.In chrome all works great on https://localhost:8080/.

Comment: I am surprised you got this to work as not supposed to work yet.  What version of express did you use to get this working?

Comment: If you see the link by Tom Rogers then you should see that it isn't working in the later versions of Express 4. I have also tested it in the latest v5alpha2 but still not working. In theory it'll work with the final release of v5. Express makes changes to the request object prototype, which screws with the http2 module.

Answer (score 2):

At time of writing this, there are known issues with using node-http2 with express, see here: https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2/issues/100